# ¿Como lleno las columnas de mi datatable mediante diferentes Listas de tipo string en C#?

Tags: c#, datatables

Me gustaría saber cual es la forma correcta de llenar de forma adecuada un datatable que tengo, la cuestión es que debo llenarlo de diferentes listas donde tengo mi información, actualmente mi datatble se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que la columna 2 este al mismo nivel que mi columna 1.

Código C#:

```
 List<List<string>> LstList = new List<List<string>>();
            LstList.Add(lstUsing.Items.Cast<string>().ToList());
            LstList.Add(lstExternal.Items.Cast<string>().ToList());
            LstList.Add(lstFunctions.Items.Cast<string>().ToList());
            LstList.Add(lstMe.Items.Cast<string>().ToList());

            DataTable dtSim = new DataTable();


            for (int i = 0; i < LstList.Count; i++)
            {
                    dtSim.Columns.Add("Col "+(i+1));
                if (i == 0) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < LstList.ElementAt(i).Count; x++)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dtSim.Rows.Add();
                        dr.SetField("Col 1", lstUsing.Items.Cast<string>().ToList().ElementAt(x));
                    }
                } else if (i==1) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < LstList.ElementAt(i).Count; x++)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dtSim.Rows.Add();
                        dr.SetField("Col 2", lstExternal.Items.Cast<string>().ToList().ElementAt(x));
                    }
                }



            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que puede hacer esto

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

List<List<int>> items = new List<List<int>>
{
    new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4 },
    new List<int> { 5,6,7,8 },
    new List<int> {4,6,8,0 }
};

// Obtener la lista más larga(Filas)
int maxRowCount = items.Max(x => x.Count);

// Anadir una columna para poder agregar todas la filas
table.Columns.Add();

// Agregando todas las filas en 0
for (int i = 0; i < maxRowCount; i++)
    table.Rows.Add(0);

// Recorrer tu lista como una Matriz 
for (int col = 0; col < items.Count; col++)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < items[col].Count; row++)
    {
        // Asignar valor a cada celda
        table.Rows[row].SetField(col, items[col][row]);
    }
    table.Columns.Add();
}

// Esto es para mostrar los datos en consola
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
    {
        Console.Write("\t {0}", item);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

*Después de agregar los datos en "Col1"* debes recorrer nuevamente el `DataTable` *`dtSim`* para llenar la información en la "Col2".

Este es tu código modificado para lograr lo que describo en líneas anteriores:

```
List<List<string>> LstList = new List<List<string>>();
LstList.Add(lstUsing.Items.Cast<string>().ToList());
LstList.Add(lstExternal.Items.Cast<string>().ToList());
LstList.Add(lstFunctions.Items.Cast<string>().ToList());
LstList.Add(lstMe.Items.Cast<string>().ToList());

DataTable dtSim = new DataTable();

// Entiendo que aquí estás agregando columnas al DataTable "dtSim"...
for (int i = 0; i < LstList.Count; i++)
{
    dtSim.Columns.Add("Col "+(i+1));
}

// Agregar información en la columna "Col1".
for (int i = 0; i < LstList.Count; i++) 
{
    for (int x = 0; x < LstList.ElementAt(i).Count; x++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dtSim.Rows.Add();
        dr.SetField("Col 1", lstUsing.Items.Cast<string>().ToList().ElementAt(x));
    }
}

// Agregar información en la columna "Col2".
for (int i = 0; i < LstList.Count; i++) 
{
    for (int x = 0; x < LstList.ElementAt(i).Count; x++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dtSim.Rows.Add();
        dr.SetField("Col 2", lstExternal.Items.Cast<string>().ToList().ElementAt(x));
    }
}
```